# Where does Password Management module's files are located in SugarCRM CE version 6.5.x?

Tags: module, passwords, sugarcrm

I want to add some more functionality in Password Management module in SugarCRM CE version 6.5.x. I have seen functionality of SugarCRM Ultimate Edititon and I want to add same functionality in Community Edition. But the problem is I don't know where the files are located to get above mentioned features. Please guide me on this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find those files in the ***custom/modules/Users*** directory and also in ***Custom/modules/Administration*** directory